# To close ionic-datepicker on clicking hardware back button in ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using `ionic-datepicker` in the app(ionic v-4), Below is the `template` code:

```
<ion-datetime  formControlName="meeting_date" display-format="MMM DD, YYYY"></ion-datetime>
```

The `datepicker`(i,e ion-datetime) will close after clicking `cancel/done` button **or**   on clicking outside.**But it not closing on clicking hardware back button**.

In the page where i am used datepicker, I tried like this:

```
ionViewWillLeave(){
        let backDrop: any = document.getElementsByTagName('ion-picker-cmp');
        if(backDrop.length > 0){
            for(let i = 0; i< backDrop.length; i++){
                backDrop[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
      }
```

But it didn't worked for me, I followed this **[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48187282/closing-ionic2-datetime-popup-while-pressing-back-button)**

Comment: do you have something else using the back button? I thought that I saw in the code that it closes any overlays first, before going back in history.

Comment: This is [the answer that I was thinking of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57027030/156388) - the overlay system registers a handler for the hardware back button event and dismisses the topmost overlay.

Answer (score 1):

First you should know whether it's focused or not, so:

```html
<ion-datetime #dateTime (ionFocus)="onDateFocused()" formControlName="meeting_date" display-format="MMM DD, YYYY"></ion-datetime>
```

And in component:

```js
onDateFocused() {
  this.focused = true; // make it false in on blur
}
```

Then register to hardware back button:

```js
this.platform.backButton.subscribe(() => {
  // this does work
});
```

Note: There is no `close` api [method](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime#methods) for `ion-datetime` as well as `open`. So there are some tricks mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45365383/how-to-close-ionic2-datetime-popup-without-clicking-cancel-button):

```js
@ViewChild("dateTime", {static: false}) dateTime : DateTime;

ngOnInit() {
  this.platform.backButton.subscribe(() => {
    this.dateTime._picker.dismiss();
  })
}
```

Comment: Inside which method i need register hardware back button, Means this code ==> **this.platform.backButton.subscribe(() => {
  // this does work
});** where i need to call?

Comment: Maybe inside `ngOnInit` you can register the event. See updated answer.

Comment: So please describe what happens.

Comment: Do `console.log('something')` in the event to see whether it works or not

Comment: And do you import `Platform` and inject it to constructor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199299/discussion-between-shankar-and-vahid-najafi).

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

This is already handled by default as part of the Ionic 4 code.

What you need to do to get this functionality though is to set `backdropDismiss` to true.

### Theory

Ionic registers a custom event `ionBackButton` for handling the hardware back button press:

- https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/utils/hardware-back-button.ts#L20

And the overlay code that manages all overlays in Ionic registers an event handler for this `ionBackButton` event, which dismisses the topmost overlay:

- https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/utils/overlays.ts#L66

However, it only does this when `backdropDismiss` is also set to true:

```
if (lastOverlay && lastOverlay.backdropDismiss) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked to me:

```
    constructor(
    public pickerCtrl: PickerController,
```

...and

```
ionViewWillLeave(){
this.pickerCtrl.dismiss();
```

**EDIT**: Recomend   use a boolean to know whether is opened or not